# How do I solve this normal line problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I got this problem I've been struggling with.

> ''Determine the points of intersection between the parabola $x^2$ and its normal at the point $(a, a^2)$''.

And here is my try to solve it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs2xO.jpg)

As you can see I cant simplify the square root expression so I must have done something wrong.

Comment: Would you mind turning the picture anti-clockwise by 90 degrees? That way, it's easier to read. Thanks.

Comment: Better idea: transcribe it into $\LaTeX$. It's the courteous thing to do.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm pretty new to this forum and I didn't know how to do it, thanks for letting me know I sure will.

Comment: I rotated the image, sorry my bad.

Comment: Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a=0$ the normal line is the $y$-axis, hence the unique intersection point is $(0,0)$.

For $a\ne 0$ the equation of the normal line at $(a,a^2)$ is $y=-\frac{1}{2a} x + (a^2+\frac 12)$,  hence the $x$-coordinate of the intersection points of the line with the parabola are the solutions of
$$x^2+\frac{1}{2a} x - (a^2+\frac 12)=0$$
One solution is obviously $x=a$ and using polynomial division we obtain:
$$x^2+\frac{1}{2a} x - (a^2+\frac 12)=(x-a)(x+a +\frac1{2a})$$

The intersection points are then $(a,a^2)$ and $(-(a +\frac1{2a}), (a +\frac1{2a})^2)$.

Comment: Ohhhhh so you came up with the other solution by doing x^2+1/2x-...=(x-a)q(x) where q(x) is the solution and then you just divided the left side with (x-a) and you used polynomial division to get the q(x), correct?

Comment: I just did it, brilliant, why didn't I thought of using polynomial division. One question, why didn't square completion work like I tried to do? Or does it work, because i couldn't simplify the square root expression if you take a look at the image.

Comment: @Muhashka, for some misterious reason I cannot open the link with the picture...

Comment: Strange, it works for me, but what I did is just -1/(2a)x-a^2+1/2=x^2 and solved for x through square completion, or the PQ-formula, same thing. And I got an expression in that square root that I couldn't simplify, but its okay, now when you showed me it will be easier to remember the solutions to these type of questions to just do polynomial division and not square completion. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you miscomputed, under the squere root in the PQ-formula you get $\frac{1}{4a^2}+4a^2+2= (2a+\frac 1{2a})^2$.

Comment: Shouldnt it be $(x+\frac{1}{4a})^2=\frac{1}{16a^2}+\frac{1}{2}+a^2$? Or am i in the completely wrong here.

Comment: It is correct, and the RHS is $(a+ \frac{1}{4a})^2$.

Comment: Ohhh hahah that's amazing, didn't see that. But why is there no x? That's where I get confused.

Comment: Nvm I see it now, thanks a lot man, I really appreciate it.